# Basic PHP For Loop issues, need assistance

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

```
// begin table centered with a border
print ('<table align = "center" border = 1>');
$index = 0; // initialize index

for ($i=0; $i <= $rows; $i++) {

    print("<tr>"); // start row
    for ($k=0; $k <= $columns; $k++) {
        $index++; // increment the index value
        // make sure we don’t exceed array bounds!
        if ($index <= $num_items) {
            tableContents(  $images[$index], 
                            $names[$index], 
                            $item_num[$index], 
                            $item_description[$index], 
                            $item_price[$index], 
                            $index);
        }
        else {
            print("<td></td>"); // make blank cell
        } // end if $index…
    } // end inner for
    print("</tr>"); // end row
} // end outer for…
print ("</table>"); // end table
```

I am creating a basic php webpage that puts items in a table, however something is wrong in my for loop and I need a little help. The arrays aren't starting at 0 it seems, my $index variable is supposed to start at 0 and then increment but its spitting out the 2nd item at the beginning instead. 
Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: @KristerAndersson if you see it carefully, `$index` only matches `$k` when it is the first row, but after that, it is `k + nc`, where `n` is the number of iterations (just like `$i`) and `c` is the number of total columns (in other words, `$index` is `0` the first time only, it never gets reinitialized).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `$index++` before you select your elements, that's why it starts at 1. Move it after the end of your if-else statement.

Also, per comment below be sure that your arrays don't get out of bounds. That is, if there are n elements in your array, the last element has the index of n-1. So, you probably want `$index < $num_items`, as well as `$k < $columns` and `$i < $rows`.

Comment: Also, as the indexes will start with `0`, make sure that your if statement should be like `if ($index < $num_items) { ... }` (strictly less than `$num_items`).